# how to get only column names from XML datasource in ssrs

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, reporting-services, msbi

I have a requirement to consume and display records from webservice in ssrs. From webserice I am able to access and display the records when I was returned as list. but I would like to return the dataset from webservice and consume the columns in ssrs dataset. So I would help to not to create class in webserivce.

Attached is the web service method screen shot and XML query written in ssrs report.

**SSRS REPORT XML QUERY:**

[image: SSRS REPORT XML QUERY]

**Webservice method:**

[image: Webservice method]

Comment: formatted the images, corrected spelling